# Azure Devops Regression test case management

Tags: azure-devops, regression, manual-testing

We have a very large application with nearly 2K testcases for regression. Our process is multiple sprints of work towards a single release. So, we use a dedicated regression test plan.

My question is how to manage regression runs? Right now, we clone the Master Regression suite or prior regression suite. This allows us to preserve the previous regression results. But this method creates new unique test cases, which doesn't keep associated bugs.

If we reset all the tests in the current suite, I know the previous runs could be seen at the test case level. However, I can't figure out how to call up historical aggregate results, for a previous run.

How should DevOps be used for managing repeat test runs?

Answer (score 0):

> How should DevOps be used for managing repeat test runs?

To repeat test, we could to insert parameters in test steps:

Create a parameter by typing a name preceded by "@" in the actions and expected results of test steps

[image]

You could check this document [Repeat a test with different data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/repeat-test-with-different-data?view=azure-devops) for some more details.

For the historical aggregate results, there is an [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/366137/manual-test-case-execution-results-in-vsts-data-an.html) about it on the Developer Community.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the feeback, but my question maybe wasn't clear. 

My issue is that I want to re-execute a test suite for regression. 

How to do this? Reset existing suite or clone a new suite?

Comment: @BenV, Got it. From my perspective I recommend reset existing suite. But just as you know, we could not call up historical aggregate results. This is also an issue on our  main forum for product issue:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/508951/unable-to-compare-historical-results-of-test-cases.html. You could this thread for some more details.